# Clearing Items with NBT Tags

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making an adventure map in Minecraft.

I've been trying to make a key that opens a door and then deletes itself from your inventory. I got it to work flawlessly without NBT tags, using a trip-wire hook as a key.

After I assigned NBT tags to it thusly,
`tripwire_hook {display:{Name:"Key",Lore:["Opens one door"]}`} the tripwire is now called a "Key" and describes exactly what it does and it even works to open the door. The command block that tests for the key in the players hand still works.

Unfortunately, the `/clear @p` command block will not recognize the item whether I add the NBT tag after "tripwire_hook" or not. Here is the command that I've used:

`/clear @p tripwire_hook 1 {display:{Name:"Key",Lore:["Opens one door"]}}`

Just to be safe, I tried the following:

`/clear @p tripwire_hook 1 1 {display:{Name:"Key",Lore:["Opens one door"]}}`

`/clear @p tripwire_hook 0 1 {display:{Name:"Key",Lore:["Opens one door"]}}`

And it will still not clear the item.

I'm using Minecraft 1.8.3.
Can anyone please advise?

Comment: Did you try using `/clear @p minecraft:tripwire_hook -1 1 {display:{Name:Key}}`?

Comment: just tried it and no dice. This is supposed to be working right? is the clear command capable of testing for nbt tags at all?

Comment: The third command in your post and the one Schism posted should work fine. What is the exact give command you're using to give yourself the key?

Comment: i'm using a command block to give myself the key as follows:

Comment: /give @p tripwire_hook 64 {display:{Name:"Key",Lore:[Opens one door]}}

Comment: That `give` command is invalid, you need to use `... 64 0 {...`. Also, I am unable to reproduce this issue. The third command (`...0 1...`) works exactly as intended. Try running it manually instead of in a command block and tell us the result

Comment: well i just tried it. same problem. the /test for command block still opens the door but the /clear will not clear. and as you suggested, i tried giving myself the item through a command. I appreciate everyone's help. is anyone using minecraft 1.8.3? because that's what i'm using.

Comment: incidentally when I try manually using the /clear command, no matter how vague or exact i get the syntax, it says "mogulus does not have 1 of tripwire_hook

Comment: I just tried again to "/give mogulus tripwire_hook 64 1 {display:{Name:"Key",Lore:["Opens one door"]}} ... then right afterwards /clear mogulus tripwire_hook 0 1 {display:{Name:"Key",Lore:["Opens one door"]}} and it said "removed 0 tripwire hooks"... so i then tried -1 1 and it said the same thing.

Comment: i'm spamming this thing and i apologize. but I just tried it in SINGLE player and it works just fine. why would it not work on a server?

Comment: I had same issue with singleplayer vs server, then given up for it (it was system for friend)

Comment: That duplicate is based around a server, and conflicting plugins with vanilla commands. It doesn't specify a version either, whereas this question does.

Comment: @Reflexive If you look at the eventual answer to this question, it also talks about plugins conflicting with vanilla commands.

Comment: @pppery Ah, my mistake. I only read the question, not the answer to this question.

Answer (score 2):

I gave myself a tripwire hook using the exact same NBT tag in Minecraft 1.8.3. After trying a few times, I was able to use this command to clear the tripwire hook:

`/clear @p tripwire_hook 0 1 {display:{Name:"Key",Lore:["Opens one door"]}}`

As the format is:

`/clear [player] [item] [data] [maxCount] [dataTag]`

Your problem is that you are running Bukkit/Spigot with the Essentials plugin, so `/clear` is overridden by the Essentials version of the command which doesn't allow you to specify the item to clear from the player's inventory.

You can prevent command blocks from using plugin commands by opening `commands.yml` and setting `command block overrides` to `*`. That makes the internal engine of the game look no further than vanilla hardcoded commands when running script from command blocks.

Comment: checked and rechecked. again, it does not work. are you playing on a server when you checked this or are  you in single player?

Comment: Singleplayer. If you are on a server, which kind of server is it?

Comment: It's on a spigot server with minecraft 1.8.3

Comment: That's exactly it. If you are running it with Essentials, /clear is overridden by the Essentials version of the command, in which you can't specify the item to clear from the player's inventory. I can't think of a solution off the top of my head to this problem, unless you could disable the command or use a different plugin apart from Essentials.

Comment: Bagel, this solved the problem. If anyone else needs help with this, the solution was to go into my servers' "commands.yml" file and under "command block overrides" type - "*"   . that makes the internal engine of the game look no further than vanilla hardcoded commands when running script from command blocks. This overrode the /clear command and theoretically any other command that has a plugin conflict or dependancy.

Comment: by the way, THANK you to everyone for helping out with this one. I am very grateful. :)