# Clear a custom item from Inventory

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-bukkit

I've looked at a few other questions on here about this, but I still can't get this to work. I've already looked at this: [Clear item with custom name?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/194098/clear-item-with-custom-name)

I'm trying to clear a custom item (just one) from a player's inventory through a command block.

Here's my command:

```
/clear @p gold_ingot 0 1 {display:{Name:"Stamped Gold Bar",Lore:["One Gold Bar","Stamped on site at Acacia Mint"],,ench:[{id: 34, lvl:1}]}}
```

Here's my error message:

[00:37:53] Removed 0 of gold_ingot from Jowaaay.

Even if I just do `/clear @p gold_ingot`, it will not remove my custom gold ingot, and will still give the same error message. I tried putting regular gold ingots into my inventory just to test that I had the correct syntax, and regular items do seem to cooperate with the /clear command.

I followed the advice given by the user who solved the above question, but I still can't get this to work. Wondering if it has to do with the enchantment on the gold ingot?

I'm running a Bukkit server with a 1.8 Minecraft. I do have Essentials installed, but I don't see how that would affect this.

Comment: Isn't that 0 value in your command the quantity, meaning that you've set the quantity of items to be removed to none?

Comment: @Texenox the 0 is the damage value of the ingot, and is fine.

Comment: Your data tag is ill-formatted, you need to close the display tag before starting the ench tag, i.e. the ending should be `...Mint"]},ench:[{id: 34, lvl:1}]}`. Although I don't think this is the issue. The error message you are getting is not normal for the clear command. I suspect you are accidentally running Essentials `/clean`/`/clearinventory` command, rather than the vanilla `/clear`. That would explain the ill-formatted message, and the removal of 0 items.

Comment: Personally, I would set the damage value to -1, which matches against all damage values.

Comment: Okay, so I tried this:
`minecraft:clear @p gold_ingot -1 1 {display:{Name:"Stamped Gold Bar",Lore:["One Gold Bar","Stamped on site at Acacia Mint"]},ench:[{id: 34, lvl:1}]}`

And now I'm getting this error message:

`[22:47:20] Could not clear the inventory of Jowaaay, no items to remove`


I fixed the formatting, I made the command a vanilla command, and I changed the damage value to -1.
So strange!

Comment: Potential duplicate of http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/229813/clearing-items-with-nbt-tags?rq=1 (I can't VTC myself). Both deal with `/clear` not working when running Essentials.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to close the `display:{}` tag then remove the extra comma. So it should look like this:

```
/clear @p gold_ingot 1 0 {display:{Name:"Stamped Gold Bar",Lore:["One Gold Bar","Stamped on site at Acacia Mint"]},ench:[{id:34,lvl:1}]}}
```

This will most likely work, I'm not sure though.